# dart upload file input type file

Tags: file-upload, go, dart, dart-html

Using Dart and Golang for a small app and looking to upload a file to server.

Found something like this and placed it in my .dart file:

```
InputElement uploadInput = query('#file'); // my input type file

  uploadInput.on.change.add((e) {
    // read file content as dataURL
    final files = uploadInput.files;
    if (files.length == 1) {
      final file = files[0];
      final reader = new FileReader();
      reader.on.load.add((e) {
       sendDatas(reader.result);
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  });
```

but getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get$on' of null
```

any idea how to handle this?

my goal: using input type file upload file to server (file size, < 1MB)

Comment: What do you try to accomplish anyway? Maybe you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673030

Comment: i just have an input type file and I want to add a file and post to server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally changed the code and this is the final working function, uploading file with DART:

```
updatefileToPlay(Event e, dynamic data, FileUploadInputElement el) {

    final files = el.files;
        if (files.length == 1) {
          final file = files[0];
          final reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onLoad.listen((e) {

            FormData data = new FormData(); // from dart:html
                data.append("file", file);

                HttpRequest.request('/upload?id='+message.id, method: 'POST', sendData: data).then((HttpRequest r) {
                  if (r.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
                      (r.status == 200 || r.status == 0)) {
                    window.alert("upload complete");
                  }
                });
          });
          reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
        }
  }
```

Comment: `The argument type 'File' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable'`

Answer (score 1):

This syntax has changed about a year ago.

try instead

```dart
uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
```

the same change is necessary here

```dart
reader.onLoad.listen((e) {
```

the `xxx.on...` syntax is only for custom events or browser events where Dart doesn't yet have direct getters.

This also works for standard browser events. You can use it like

```dart
uploadInput.on['change'].listen((e) => doSomething());
```

Comment: hi man, thanks for the reply. now I'm getting something like this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get$onChange' of null

Comment: Can you please check if `uploadInput` has a value before this line is executed?

Comment: it doesn't. oh does it need `@observable uploadInput = 0` ?

Comment: I did miss this one. You should use `querySelector` instead of `query` (but `query` should work too I guess but it's marked `@deprecated` for about a year and I never tried it). Do you use Polymer? `@observable` is usually used in Polymer elements. It could be used on its own too but your code doesn't indicate anything in that direction. Check if your input element has the id `file`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'my input has `#file`'. You input element needs to look like `<input type="file" id="file">`. `id="file"` is the important part to make it work with `querySelector('#file');`. You could also use `querySelector('input[type=file]');` then the id attribute isn't necessary. You can use CSS selectors with `querySelector()` (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: When you use polymer you can do the binding in HTML `<input type="file" on-change="{{fileChangeHandler}}">` and in Dart `void fileChangeHandler(Event e) { doSomething(); }` instead ofquerySelector` and `uploadInput.onChange.listen`